# Google Books Library and Prices

Tags: export, google-books

I am currently using Google Books quickly to create a list of books that I can sell.

Is there a way to export this list to a next service (or a Google feature I am missing) so that I can attach prices?

Note: Anything that is not dynamic will not work for me (around 200 books). I am cleaning my library by shelf and updating as I go along. Then my relative checks the prices on Amazon/ Other sites (or even calls bookstores) manually.

In this question: [Getting the link to a public bookshelf in googlebooks](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5208/getting-the-link-to-a-public-bookshelf-in-google-books) [*Now Solved*] I <strike>try</strike> am able to get the XML (dynamic/live version) *without* downloading it. So I already know how to download the XML.

I am looking for clean way from Google Books (I am going to be placing reviews later for some of the books) to another service/application.

Answer (score 2):

If you select a "shelf" of books, then pull down the Options tab, you'll find an "export to XML" option. I was able to read that XML file with Excel 2003 and it generated a table containing the titles, ISBNs, etc. That spreadsheet is a good start, or you could export *that* as .CSV and pretty much anything will read that.

Comment: Thanks I already know how to get the xml at a certain time.I have updated the question .

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't know how to do that with Google Books. I am working on a similar project but I have found it easier to maintain the list of books as a list of ISBN's and to get pricing data programmatically from http://isbndb.com. You might also take a look at http://www.librarything.com if you haven't run across that yet.

Comment: Alright isbndb looks promising. Is there a way to bulk add the books ?